# Get total amount spent for a Stripe customer

Tags: stripe-payments

What would be the easiest way to calculate the total amount a specific Stripe customer has spent?

```
fn(stripeCustomerId) -> totalAmountSpent
```

I don't believe there are any API endpoints that allow aggregate queries, so I'm guessing I'd have to enumerate all payment intents or invoices and manually calculate the total?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, there aren't Stripe API endpoints for aggregate queries! I'd [list](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list#list_charges-customer) Charges or Payment Intents specifying the Customer parameter and then sum on your side.

As an alternative, you could use something like [Stripe's Sigma](https://stripe.com/sigma) to create SQL queries from your data, but this feature comes at an additional cost.

Comment: Stripe Sigma looks interesting. I haven't come across that before.